# tab separation problem

Tags: c#

I usually used this to create tab separated files for excel:

```
sb.AppendLine(String.Format(@"{0}\t{1}" ...
```

Strangely it does not work anymore. Any ideas?

C

Comment: What doesn't work? Does .NET crash? Does the file not open in Excel?

Comment: Excel 'sees' \t but does not recognise it as tab. Removing the @ worked. Thanks Preet Sangha. The @ seems to do some weird encoding ...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

surely no @ symbol `sb.AppendLine(String.Format("{0}\t{1}"...`

The @ symbol tells the compiler to interpret the string literally so it places 2 characters  a `backslash` and a `t` in string. If you don't use the @ symbol it tells the compiler to interpret the string so `\t` is changed into the escape character for `TAB`.